# How do I change the command sent by TRAMP in Emacs when using plink on Windows?

Tags: emacs, putty, plink, tramp

I have the following in my .emacs:

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
```

When I run `C-x C-f /plink:some_session:/` in Emacs where `some_session` is a defined session in PuTTY (which has all information saved such as location of private key, username, connection type=ssh, etc.), tramp issues the following command (copied from *Messages* buffer):

```
Tramp: Sending command ‘plink -ssh -t some_session " env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ ' /bin/sh " && exit || exit’
```

You can see that it passes the `-ssh` flag to `plink`. Everything works fine when I am connecting to a remote host which expects the ssh connection on port 22.

However, I have a remote host which I need to connect to on port 2222. If I save a session (`some_new_session`) in PuTTY and try to connect using the following commands (or the PuTTY gui) this is what happens:

- using the PuTTY GUI

  - works fine
- `plink some_new_session`

  - Issued from `cmd.exe` - works fine and am able to connect
- `plink -ssh some_new_session`

  - Issued from `cmd.exe` - does not work

I have debugged the issue and found that when the `-ssh` flag is passed to `plink` it attempts to connect on port 22 anyway even though the saved session states to use port 2222. Essentially when given `-ssh` it ignores the port saved in the session (which feels like a bug).

If I try to connect using `C-x C-f /plink:some_new_session:/` in Emacs the command issued is:

```
Tramp: Sending command ‘plink -ssh -t some_new_session " env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ ' /bin/sh " && exit || exit’
```

I actually do not need the `-ssh` flag because the connection type being SSH is saved in the PuTTY session. Also the `-ssh` flag forces the connection to be through port 22 even though the session has it saved as port 2222.

My question is:

**How can I change the command issued by tramp so it does not call plink with the -ssh flag?**

Comment: Have you tried modifiying `tramp-methods` to alter how it invokes `plink` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plink` method is intended to use a hostname. If you want to (reuse) a session, use `plinkx`, like `C-x C-f /plinkx:some_session:/` and `C-x C-f /plink:some_new_session:/`.

Comment: This is good information. I was unaware of the plinkx method and have changed my default method `(setq tramp-default-method "plinkx")` to avoid the problem entirely!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect modifying the following will resolve the problem. The value I'm setting here is simply the default `tramp-login-args` value for the "plink" method.

n.b. The other standard tramp methods using plink are: "psftp", "pscp", and "plinkx".

```el
(eval-after-load "tramp"
  '(setf (cadr (assq 'tramp-login-args (cdr (assoc "plink" tramp-methods))))
         '(("-l" "%u") ("-P" "%p") ("-ssh") ("-t") ("%h") ("\"")
           ("env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ '") ("/bin/sh") ("\""))))
```

Comment: This works after removing the `("-ssh")`. Great piece of e-lisp.